# Expand application bar in Windows Phone 7 app from code

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I need to know if there is a way to expand the application bar in Windows Phone app from code.

Here is a demo of the application bar states:
[image]

Comment: Someone else already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459664/show-applicationbar-menu-programmatically-wp7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there is no API for 3rd party developers to do this, the application bar is a bit of an oddity on WP7. If you view a picture full size in the picture hub it will automatically expand the menu for you. Perhaps this is a UI mistake or perhaps we'll all gain access to this API in a future update. It's worth checking back on.

Comment: Native apps on WP7 are not built using Silverlight like 3rd party apps, so they are not a good indication of what APIs might be exposed in the future to Silverlight, especially in weird cases like these.

Comment: Interesting, that sounds like a good reason for some inconsistencies. But that doesn't change my opinion that there is a good chance 3rd party API's will be added for UI precedents that they have established in native apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't (Really, read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) first next time.). And why would you want to do such madness anyway. The UI should react to the users interaction, not the other way around!

Comment: Thank you. The doc you have pointed to does not say (or am I just failing to see this particular part) that it is impossible to expand the application bar. I've read the doc first. I have seen people use triggers inside of the app bar declaration, and thought maybe they were the way to do it.

Comment: He might want to expose the menu controls from UI interaction elsewhere on the screen. E.g. selecting a listed item to open a menu specific to that item.

Comment: As for the motivation, I just needed the user to be able to read the text beneath the Application Bar Icons when the app is ran for the first time, since the user is not familiar with the UI at first.

Comment: The user will click the ellipsis if they're unfamiliar with what the buttons are for. That's the natural behaviour for the entire platform (and very intuitive , really).

Comment: The text below is also designed for buttons. Putting arbitrary text that does not do anything on this location is a bad user experience. If your user-experience isn't clear, then maybe you should rethink it to match the WP7 paradigm

Comment: I just don't want to use the common record button with a filled circle, so I use a wave image. Some users may need to see that in this app it is a record button. Having them able to see it (with text underneath) at start-up would be a good feature. I think that the lack of functionality of a particular control should not be "defended" by rhetoric about its' usefulness.