# How can I programmatically open the ApplicationBar in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

In Windows Phone, how can I programmatically open the ApplicationBar, to let users read the button labels at app start time without the need to tap on the corner dots ("...")?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973079/expand-application-bar-in-windows-phone-7-app-from-code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show applicationbar menu programmatically (wp7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459664/show-applicationbar-menu-programmatically-wp7)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there **isn't a way** you can achieve this due to the default behavior. The `ApplicationBar` is meant to be expanded by the user when he taps on the dots `'...'`. You will have to make the user tap on the three dots and not have a way to do it programmatically.

Hopefully in the future, Windows Phone will allow this.