# How to navigate to another page using application bar in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to navigate to another page, very first next to main page i added new page in that additionally i added application bar, now i want to navigate to third page after i click menu item in the application bar, application bar with menu item should be shown  in the third page,without removing it in the third page.I am working in Visual studio 2012 . how can i acheive this task. i defined application bar in this way.

Answer (score 0):

@lokesh, it seems, that there's no possibility to programmatically show the application bar. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459664/show-applicationbar-menu-programmatically-wp7)

So, the first part of your task can be done quite easily, just add a menuItem to your application bar, that will marshal the navigation(it can be done with delegate)

```
appBarNavigateSomewhere.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            appBarNavigateSomewhere_Click(sender, e, page);
        };
```

then:

```
public void appBarNavigateSomewhere_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, PhoneApplicationPage page)
        {
            page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(SomePage, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

But the ability to show this appBar at the third page, right after navigation happened, cannot be done.

---

Please note, that NavigationService.Navigate() could be used only from some page, that's why I'm adding PhoneApplicationPage object to the method.

Comment: Ok now my question is, I am having 3 buttons, i want to place it in constant position in phone application page, so that when i click that buttons I  want to navigate to respective page of each button.How can i achieve this task?If i need to use it in TabView methods ?how it is possible.. any help?,for achieving this task i used application bar,hope i cant use that method as per Olter answer.Any other answers???

Comment: @lokesh, if you don't want to use an application bar, you could simply create a common User Control and then add it to the bottom of your every page. So, you just create some "BottomControlPanel" Use control, add three buttons there and use `NavigationService.Navigate()` method in these buttons' event hanlders at every page(remember, you need to know the current page to use navigationservice, you can't write down handler at the user control code itself.). That's a bit harsh solution, but also will work.